# why bigquery return blank result

Tags: google-bigquery

support team,

Today I encounter a strange performance in BQ. I tested and ran the Standard SQL with UDF to a smaller table which only include the necessary column from the original table, and it works. Then when I ran the SQL with UDF to the original table which is from Data Transfer, the query completed in 40s, but it is strange that the results is blank as in the attachment below. Pls notice, it is not empty in the result, it is totally bank without any info.
[image]

And when check the "Query History". You can see the query is completed with info as below:

```
Job ID  broject_name: ...bquijob_6f97bb2c_15b908ee77a  
Creation Time   Apr 21, 2017, 2:52:14 PM  
Start Time  Apr 21, 2017, 2:52:14 PM  
End Time    Apr 21, 2017, 2:52:54 PM  
Bytes Processed 1.24 GB  
Bytes Billed    1.24 GB  
Billing Tier    1  
Destination Table   
project_name: ..._6ccaf9a9bf937b63344d66ed12236b3788d70706.anon35e0c727_0922_4cf2_b5c3_d0f5d12b726a 
Use Legacy SQL  false
```

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: You should rather post such issues at a [BigQuery Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks for point this out, I will post this in the tracker.

Comment: sure, no problem - it fits there much better as it definitely looks like an issue vs programming question!

Comment: Could you please also include complete project id, which is needed for investigation?

Comment: @xuejian, thanks, I posted the project id in the issue tracker.